# Branching in TFS 2010 and being forced to re-download the code

Tags: version-control, tfs

When i create a branch from the mainline in TFS 2010 i have to download all of the code i have just branched.

I already have the latest mainline version on my laptop so why is TFS requiring me to effectively download whats already on my hard disk?

Even if i copy the mainline files into a folder and map the new branch to this folder it still performs a fully recursive get and chokes our bandwith for 30 minutes or so.

This seems like such a waste of time and bandwith - is their a workaround/procedure that i am not aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For faster switching between branches, give the `tf get /remap` option a try. From Brian Harry's blog:

> This is a new
>   option on tf get that is intended to
>   be used when you want to switch your
>   workspace from one branch to another
>   in the same code base.  You first
>   change the workspace mapping and then
>   issue a tf get /remap.  Because a
>   large percentage of the files in two
>   related branches are frequently
>   identical, this command optimizes for
>   that.  Rather than downloading all the
>   content, it will only download the
>   things that are different between the
>   two branches.  I can reduce the get of
>   a very large workspace from 10's of
>   minutes to a few seconds.

Note that this requires TFS 2008 SP1 or later.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf(VS.90).aspx

Comment: this is exactly the kind of functionality i was hoping to find.  Much like the SVN switch command.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, this saved me 1.5 Gb of bandwith everytime I made a branch. I too was looking for SVN switch alternate. Branches should be able to be throw away items that are simple to use. I'm amazed this isn't built in to the GUI!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that  is that TFS doesn't know that you have the branch downloaded.  The act of "getting" actually puts a record in the TFS database that indicates which version of the code you have in your workspace.  That way, it knows whether you have latest or not.

I'm surprised that a "get" is taking more than 30 minutes.  Is your TFS server remote?  Are you getting more binaries than you need to?  If you have a remote server, you may want to consider using the TFS proxy to help with performance.  Though it won't solve this particular issue you have, it may speed things up for other developers.

One final question:  why are you branching so much?  Though I understand the idea of branch on feature, and that it increases the number of times that you'll need to branch, it should still be a relatively infrequent occurrence.  And if it is rare, then, yes, the thirty minutes to download may be annoying, but you'll need to ask yourself if it really is a problem.

Comment: Yes our TFS server is remote, and the solution contains many projects, some containing lots of media etc.  Hence the lengthly downloads at busy times of the day.  I am not branching 'so much',  Just when features and the complexities of different customer requirements demand it.  Sometimes this is as little as twice a month, sometimes a lot more.  Either way you shouldnt have to download an entire set of something that you already have on your machine - which is what SVN does with the switch command.  Luckily TFS has remap as highlighted below :-)

Comment: the /remap is a great idea.  We hadn't needed to do that yet, but it's a good one to put in my toolkit.

Comment: "why are you branching so much?... ...  it should still be a relatively infrequent occurrence." I disagree with this statement. You should be able to spin up a branch, test and idea and prove it works very easily. I don't expect my version control system to dictate to me how I should develop code. Try git or subversion, they make it trivial and I'm very pleased to have found the remap functionality of TFS here.

Comment: @toxaq - My point was that if it is a 30 minute task to branch, and you're doing it less than once a day, that's probably tenable.  If you're branching constantly during the workday, then there *might* be something wrong with your process.  And if your TFS server is remote and you have a slow connection, you might have to change your process to fit the realities of the situation.

Comment: That is the crux of the original question though. Previously with TFS for me it was a 30 min operation as I do work remotely. Now, with remap, I can create a branch and be working on it in 2 mins (of config time) because remap allows me to keep the code I've already got (Gbs of it). I'm not disagreeing that processes shouldn't be reconsidered but I certainly believe that a VCS should not have any say over how you should develop which is why SVN & Git are so popular.

Comment: @toxaq - true, but the concepts between the two are different. TFS was never designed to be a DVCS - in fact, the VCS part of TFS is only part of the product, there's significant substance behind the application lifecycle management pieces.  But the /remap is a very nice thing to have, no?