# How to have two repository paths mapped to one local path in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

1. we have 2 branches of code in tfs 2010 such as enhancement and support
2. Most of the developers work on enhancement as well as support.
3. Now, We want to create two different work spaces and map it to one local folder as we have all our virtual directories mapped to that local folder and dll registered from that location.

However, TFS does not allow this!! So what is the alternative? Also
mapping to two different local folders will occupy more spaces on each individual developer's machine.

Comment: What would happen when a local file is changed but you only want to apply the changes to one branch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Branching in TFS 2010 and being forced to re-download the code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786054/branching-in-tfs-2010-and-being-forced-to-re-download-the-code)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. As Stuart mentioned in his question - TFS is not able to decide where to do check-in, if you try to check-in your changes on one file mapped from two branches.